# Moving logo downward in LateX poster

Tags: logos

I cannot seem to be able to move a logo downward in a latex poster I am making. It is a circular logo, and I increased the size so it would be more easily seen and now it cuts the top of the logo off the top of the page.

Here is the code I am using:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{

headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes

colspacing=1em, % Column spacing

bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster

bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster

borderColor=lightblue, % Border color

headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)

headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)

headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes

boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes

textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded

eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left

headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header

headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded

headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes

%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation

linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}

{\includegraphics[height=8em]{FAMU.jpg}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsc{Sustainable Micro-housing Unit}\vspace{0.5em}}
{\textsc{\{Edward Major II\} \newline \hspace{12pt} FAMU-FSU Department of Civil Engineering}}
{\includegraphics[height=8em]{FSU.jpg}} % Second university/lab logo on the right
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the problem. The document class is particularly critical in this case.